# How to mount MTP like a drive in /dev?

Tags: adb, data-recovery, mount, partitions, mtp

I am trying to recover some files on my android device, but without success. So I would like to try tools like photorec, but they need a physically mounted device. Or rather, for the moment photorec makes me recover files only from /dev/sdx, so I need to mount the mtp device like this. For now I have tried this solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446180/how-to-mount-smartphone-to-recover-files but jmtpfs gives me an error.
And and lastly this [Android system partition image on pc or sdcard](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32202/android-system-partition-image-on-pc-or-sdcard).
The problem is that in recent versions of android (I tried 10 and 11), in the block folder there is no stl6, but a lot of sdx partitions.

Comment: Cross-posted from Ubuntu.SE: https://askubuntu.com/q/1365727/331791

Comment: you cannot recover files from android device, I doubt photorec did recover anything

Comment: MTP exposes emulated storage, and that too as a file transfer protocol, not the storage itself. Recovering data requires access to raw `userdata` partition or the bare filesystem of the partition (mounted at `/data`): https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526. But on modern devices data recovery is extremely unlikely due to locked bootloader, encryption, and use of flash filesystem (`f2fs`).